# restore .dbb dump file using java or c# and take backup as textfile

Tags: java, c#, c++, database-restore

I have .dbb database dump file. I want to restore it and take it's backup in text file by developing application using java or c#. I don't know about .dbb extension file. I searched on internet but not found any satisafactory information about it.  Please guide me how to deal with .dbb. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to restore, the database? And why you need to write it to text file?

Comment: I want .dbb file data into text file, I search on internet and found, .dbb is database backup file, that's why I need to restore it in database and then dump that data as text so it can be readable.